# disable any layout for static pages with high_voltage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, high-voltage

I am using high_voltage gem on a Rails 4 project. I have built two static pages so far. Following [this](https://www.helpsheets.co/questions/132-high_voltage-some-protect-select-pages) tutorial here, I added an 'override' behavior for disabling the layout and disabling the user authentication. But still it is using the default 'application layout'. Did anyone else face the problem? Thank in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Found it.

```
# config/initializers/high_voltage.rb
HighVoltage.configure do |config|
  config.layout = 'your_layout'
end
```

from [gem wiki](https://github.com/thoughtbot/high_voltage)